# Steps sequence to deploy a .NET Core Worker Service into a Linux systemd service unit/daemon

Tags: linux, .net-core, debian, packaging, dotnet-publish

[This article](https://medium.com/bluekiri/packaging-a-net-core-service-for-ubuntu-4f8e9202d1e5) offers a step-by-step guide to deploy a .NET Core Worker Service into a linux systemd service unit/daemon. Thanks to the author I successfully achieved the desired result.

There is one thing, however, I am finding counter-intuitive in the whole process: to have these pre-make build cleanup steps - before creating the `.tar` file - when eventually the `rules` `makefile` will define the `publish` (and implicitly a `build`) command in build override target.
I assume `dh_make` works on a `tar` and that's why we create it before the `publish`, but would not the cleanup steps fit better if put after the `publish` execution ?

Could anyone clarify that?